# Do I need to explicitly define a predicate to use logical quantifiers?

Tags: notation, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I'm not a maths natural so I'm not sure if this is a silly question. I was wondering, is it acceptable to structure an expression involving logical quantifiers without using function notation?

For example, can I write

$\exists a \in A f(a) < 3$

or do I need to define $P(a)$ etc. first and write like so:

$\exists a \in A P(a)$ where $P(a) = (f(a) < 3)$ or something weird like that (not quite sure how to write what $P(a)$ is)?

The first option is much shorter but I don't know if it is valid. If it is valid, is it acceptable to show as above or should I additionally put brackets around the predicate part with a space in between?

E.g. $\exists a \in A \text{ } (f(a) < 3)$

Comment: tbh, if i read/wrote this in a paper, i think id go for the first or the third (but with a s.t. or “such that” between predicate and quantifier) and only the 2nd if the predicate was hard to understand or i am going to refer to it a lot. Even then i would probably define it in a seperate sentence or something, as a word rather than by P(x). im struggling to think of many times ive seen the second, the most common is definitely the first (for me at least)

Comment: $f(a)<3$ is a viable predicate.  You are not *required* to supply an alias, though you may if you wish to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well..., $~\exists x{\in}A~(x=3)~$ *is* a well-formed-formula that claims "Something in $A$, is equal to three."

This is equivalent to just saying: "Three is in $A$."  $$3\in A\quad\equiv\quad\exists x{\in}A~(x=3)$$

You are not *required* to provide an alias for the predicate, though you *may* if you wish to do so.   Where $P(x)$ is an alias for $(x=3)$ you may substitute.   It should be noted in the margin if not made clear nearby in the surrounding text.$$\exists x{\in}A~P(x)\tag{where $P(x):= (x=3)$}$$

---

PS: Yes: spacing and brackets do help readability.

Comment: Ah good point, I'll edit the question to make the use of the quantifier necessary.